Reminder: Please DON’T answer "bad" questions
If you find a poorly phrased question (see bottom), please don't waste your time on writing a good answer. Rather use one of the following approaches:

Improve the question to an acceptable level, only then answer it.
Downvote and leave a comment to explain to the asker why his question needs improvement
Downvote and vote to close or flag "very low quality"

If your answer is good enough, it makes it hard for us to get rid of the terrible question, as we don't like to destroy your effort. On the other hand, we really don't want to keep the bad question either. It makes for hard decisions and by following the community guideline to rather keep something when in doubt, you are essentially protecting bad content that way, or create work for others to edit it into shape.

What are "bad" questions?

half a dozen jumbled questions in one post
illegible texts full of slang, abbreviations, half-sentences and half-thoughts
hard to discern what is being asked


This is very good advice.

Note we have a badge to encourage editing what you answer going out soon.
